# On a specific Fourier series on solenoids

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In [[1]](https://www.fim.uni-passau.de/fileadmin/dokumente/fakultaeten/fim/lehrstuhl/ritter/publications/hewittritter81.pdf), Hewitt and Ritter define a sequence of operators $S_n$ on $\mathcal{L}_1(\sum_{a})$, where $\sum_a$ is a compact abelian group called $a$-adic solenoid. This operators can be realized as convolutions with certain trigonometric polynomials: 
$$
S_nf(x,t)= \sum_{\alpha\in C_j}\hat f(\chi_\alpha)\chi_\alpha(t,x)=  f\ast P_n(x,t), 
$$
where $P_n = \sum_{\alpha\in C_j}\chi_\alpha$. My question is:

> Is there a $C>0$ such that $\|P_n\|_1\leq C$, for all $n$?

I'd be also interested in knowing if moreover $\{P_n\}_n$ form an approximate identity.

My motivation is to try to obtain Young-type convolution inequalities for these groups. More specifically, if one fixes an invariant and compatible metric on $\sum_a$, I would like to obtain an inequality of the type
$$
\|f\ast P_n\|_{Lip} \leq C \|f\|_{Lip}, 
$$
for all $n$ and all Lipschitz function $f$. Here, $\|g\|_{Lip}$ denotes the smallest Lipschitz constant for $g$.

[1] Hewitt, Ritter, Fourier series on certain solenoids, Math. Ann., 1981.

Comment: This is not a definite answer, but by analogy with usual Fourier series indexed by ${\bf Z}$, these $P_n$ look like Dirichlet kernels rather than Fejer kernels, and hence my first **guess** is that they will not form a bounded sequence in the $L^1$-norm. In general, summability kernels for Fourier analysis on LCA groups will have bad properties if they are just unweighted sums of characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @YemonChoi. I understand, it seems unlikely that in this case we'd have the desired bound. For the torus we use the very specific properties of the group to produce, out of the Dirichlet Kernels, the approximate identity formed by the Fejér kernels. It'd be interesting to know if in this case it's also possible to combine the $P_n$ in order to obtain better kernels in this sense.

Comment: I am reasonably confident (but not certain without checking) that you can get analogues of the Fejer kernel on any LCA group G, by taking the "Dirichlet kernels" and convolving them with themselves. The basic idea is that if U is a symmetric compact neighbourhood of the origin in the **dual group** $\widehat{G}$, then you let $D_U$ be the characteristic function/indicator function of U, normalised to have $L^2$-norm equal to $1$, and consider $D_U*D_U$. For solenoids, maybe there is something under the name "Bochner-Fejer kernel" which IIRC occurs in some old work on almost-periodic functions?

Comment: Thank you again @YemonChoi for your comment, I will look into this. I'll post if I find something.